# Why can't a localized state thermalize?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, many-body, locality

I am trying to get my head around Anderson localization and many body localization, and currently am looking at [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.1568.pdf). In the first paragraph the author states

> First, since a localized state cannot thermalize, it implies the
>   breakdown of the eigenstate thermalization hypothesis [3–5] and thus
>   the emergence of statistical physics from quantum mechanics.

I'm unsure exactly what is meant by the claim that a localized state cannot thermalize, or why this must be true, can anyone help elaborate on this point?